# Problem with an Unhandeled Promise Rejection in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have two functions: one to take a picture from the camera and the other to process that image,
when I run the code the following warning is display:

"[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...ImageManipulator.manipulate...')]"

Here are my imports

```
 import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions'
 import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker'
 import * as ImageManipulator from 'expo-image-manipulator'
```

And here are the two functions, I should also point that the code was working before I implemented the processImage() function

```
getImageFromCamera = async () => {
        const cameraPermission = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
        const cameraRollPermission = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);

        if (cameraPermission.status === 'granted' && cameraRollPermission.status === 'granted') {
            let capturedImage = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
                allowsEditing: true,
                aspect: [4, 3],
            });
            //If the user didn't cancel the picture
            if (!capturedImage.cancelled) {
                console.log(capturedImage);
                this.processImage(capturedImage.uri);
            }
        }

    }

processImage = async (imageUri) => {
    try {

        let processedImage = await ImageManipulator.manipulate(
            imageUri,
            [
                { resize: { width: 400 } }
            ],
            { format: 'png' }
        );
        

    } catch (error) {
        Alert.alert('Failed to process the Image' )
        
    }
    
    console.log(processedImage);
    this.setState({ imageUrl: processedImage.uri });

}
```

I'm a beginner with React Native and with Expo and I can't for the life of me identify the error, If you guys need any more info let me know

The promise fails in the `let processedImage = await ImageManipulator.manipulate`

But I can't figure out why

Comment: `Permissions.askAsync` or `ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync` or `ImageManipulator.manipulate` probably as an error - use try/catch as you should be doing to handle errors from await

Comment: @JaromandaX Ty for the quick response :D, after playing a bit with the try/catch the error is in the ImageManipulator.manipulate, let me update the post.

Comment: same error? or now you get `'Failed to process the Image'`

Comment: I get the 'Failed to process the Image' alert

Comment: so, you've now found where the error is ... I don't know what it is ... perhaps the `error` argument will tell you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the expo documentation [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/). As per the documentation, there is no such method `manipulate`. Instead of this, you should be using `manipulateAsync`. So please update this line

```
let processedImage = await ImageManipulator.manipulate
```

to this

```
let processedImage = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync
```

and it should be good.